# Java SE Embedded in arm linux

Tags: java

According to ORACLE's doc [Quick Start for Platform Developers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/plat-dev-quick-start.htm) I used Jrecreate and got JRE .

I copied JRE to my Arm Linux, `cd ./bin` and inputted `java -version`.

But terminal displayed：`-sh:java:not found`

Do I miss any Share Library?

Comment: Use ./java I also recommend learning some basic linux knowledge before doing things like this.

Comment: Clerical errors,I used ./.Also I added path to $PATH.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need some lib.and i used uclibc that don't support JRE.

Answer (score 0):

If you want an executable from your current directory to be callable by name you need `.` to be included in your `$PATH`, which isn't the case by default due to security concerns. Otherwise you have to provide an absolute or relative path to the executable such as `./java`.

Another solution, which is the most common for `java` and other language development tools / runtime environments, would be to include the absolute path to your Java install's `bin` directory in the `$PATH` so that you can run `java` from anywhere. This is often done by first setting a `$JAVA_HOME` environment variable, then including `$JAVA_HOME/bin` in your path :

```
export JAVA_HOME="/usr/bin/java/"  # or whatever your install path is
export PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$PATH"
```

Answer (score 0):

Either enter the location where your `java` executable actually is or add the java binary to your `PATH` environment variable.

If you read [Oracles documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/embedded/develop-apps-platforms/deploy-embedded-jre.htm#BCGBDGIC), you need to do this after having run `Jrecreate`. (Please adapt *`destDir`*)

> Recursively copy `destDir` from the host to the device directory where you want the JRE installed. For example:
>
> ```
> $ scp -r /tmp/SmallJRE/* root@target:/opt/local/ejdk<version>/
> ```
>
> If necessary, update the device's PATH environment variable to include the `bin/` directory of the JRE. For instance:
>
> ```
> $ PATH=$PATH:/opt/local/ejdk<version>/bin/
> $ export PATH
> ```